# select row value in a table with a new line space

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a list and in my first item I have an enter, space or new line space and when I try to select this row, I can't select it

```
SELECT * 
FROM patologias 
where patologias='Artritis'
```

or

```
SELECT * 
FROM patologias
where patologias='\nArtritis'
```

[image: comand line resul mariadb]

[phpstorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EbEg.jpg)

in phpstorm appear a icon(new line or enter) before word "Artritis".

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to achieve here, but if you want to ignore the white space, you can use this:  SELECT * FROM patologias where patologias like '%Artritis%'

Comment: If you use like, it should work. % matches any char, so sql will search for any string containing, artritis.

Comment: Use Trim function and see if that works

Comment: @Sarhang thank you, if I use it like with % work  fine.